# Laravel - Login Fail after adding mutator on User id

Tags: laravel, hashids

I have classic user id table where the primary key is BigIncrement.

I need to hide the id value from user. So my idea is to use hashIds packages.
What I've done to mask the id is by creating mutator on id column:

```
public function getIdAttribute($id)
{ 
    return Hashids::connection(User::class)->encode($id);
}
```

The masking working good, but problem happens when I try to login.
Seems the login session is not created.

My questions are:

1. Why the login is failed after creating id mutator? I assume that to create session it involve the id value
2. Any better way to mask the id, besides using mutator?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind masking the ID? Likely the reason you're not logging in is that `encode($id)` will not match the value in the database (which is not encoded), so even if email/password is correct, logging in by the found ID wouldn't work (or something along those lines; I don't use the default auth package much)

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for the answer. I need to mask the id for creating the link.. so instead of https://myweb.com/user/1, I think it would be nice if the link is https://myweb.com/user/[some hashid]

Comment: @yangsopiana in such case, just create another column, and store some other value in it. And use that value in the link (you could store the hash in that column, Just make sure its unique).

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason to use the ID in that case. ArunAS has the right approach; another column or a differently named mutator, like `getEncryptedIdAttribute()`, then `$user->encrypted_id` instead of `$user->id`. Basically, using the same name for the mutator as the column will cause these unintended side-effects.